# How To Use ReportViewer

Tags: wpf

//Declare a object

```
 ReportViewer rv = new ReportViewer();
```

Error 1

```
The type 'System.Windows.Forms.UserControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
```

You must add a reference to assembly

```
 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. c:\users\dsingh\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Rd\Rd\MainWindow.xaml.cs  27  13  Rd
```

Comment: Is ReportViewer a userControl ?

Comment: yes  Shaminder Any Solutions

Comment: your error answers your question, try adding windows forms assembly. It will help you.

Comment: But How T Add Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error itself answers your question, try adding windows forms assembly.
Follow the following Steps

1. Right click on your project in Visual  Studio
2. Click on `Add Reference` option
3. Click on `.Net` Tab
4. Scroll For `System.Windows.Forms` Component Name
5. Click on `Add Reference`

and don't forget to add reference in the window or page start tag.
Follow the link provided in the below comment from FredrikRedin

Comment: Shaminder  thanx For previous Suggestion Now Next Step To show A Image In .rdlc Report But giving error                                                             An error occurred during local report processing.

Comment: The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.
            Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common

Comment: your are using report viewer's older version on 2012, follow these links
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8287e1cd-767e-463c-8cb0-60c275fe5ed6/compile-error-on-rdlc-details-the-report-definition-has-an-invalid-target-namespace?forum=vsreportcontrols

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/f2a6d0a8-6c6f-467b-a1e2-210d7b0c42ec/error-the-report-definition-is-not-valid-details-the-report-definition-has-an-invalid-target?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Shaminder S Aujla Any Other Solution Like Using NugetPackage Or Other Things.

Comment: yes, try Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer in nugget console